# Looping through array causes gradual slowness and eventual buffer seize

Tags: python, mysql-connector

I am looping through a large array of about 50k items that I grabbed from a cursor and converted to a list.  Each list item has 6 attributes, example of one line:

["John","Doe","john.doe@gmail.com","123 happy lane","Irvine","CA"]

In a loop for each item in this list, I am grabbing the first name, last name, and email, and using them within the loop to send an email out.

Eventually, the loop slows to a crawl after about 1000 iterations.

I tried doing the (buffered=True) trick on the cursor but that didn't seem to help.

Here is my code:

```
try:
    for item in rows:
        #time.sleep(1)
        with smtplib.SMTP_SSL(SMTPserver, SMTPport, context=context) as server:
            server.login(SMTPemail, SMTPpassword)
            entireemail = ''' email content here   '''
            msgText = MIMEText(entireHTML, 'html') 
            msgAlternative.attach(msgText)
            server.sendmail(strFrom, item[3], msgRoot.as_string())
            mycursor.execute("UPDATE admin_contacts.mailing2019728 SET email_sent =  '"+str(datetime.datetime.today())+"' WHERE id = '"+str(item[0])+"'")
            logFile.write(str(datetime.datetime.today())+"' WHERE id = '"+str(item[0])+"'\n")

        print(str(datetime.datetime.today()) + ': email sent to ' + item[3])
        logFile.write(str(datetime.datetime.today()) + ': email sent to ' + item[3] + "\n")
```

It starts off quick enough, popping out 2 emails a second, but then slows down to a crawl after about 500-1000.  Eventually it times out, here is the trace:

```
 "Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "emailer.py", line 61, in <module>
    with smtplib.SMTP_SSL(SMTPserver, SMTPport, context=context) as server:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/smtplib.py", line 1031, in __init__
    source_address)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/smtplib.py", line 251, in __init__
    (code, msg) = self.connect(host, port)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/smtplib.py", line 336, in connect
    self.sock = self._get_socket(host, port, self.timeout)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/smtplib.py", line 1037, in _get_socket
    self.source_address)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/socket.py", line 727, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/socket.py", line 716, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
OSError: [Errno 105] No buffer space available
```

Is anything obviously wrong with my code?

Comment: Can you give a full traceback? Where is this buffer full error coming from? None of your loop code should do that, so it's probably something else you're using that's buffering something, and the exception should make that clearer.

Comment: The exact error I got was: “error: [Errno 105] No buffer space available”

I forgot to copy the trace.  I will next time it happens, it's currently running.  Am I running too many executes?  Should I be closing the cursor and reopening a new one each time?

Comment: Just added the trace, it seems like its the SMTPLIB call that it's having trouble with.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can separate the lists in sublists and run a multi processes
https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the for loop inside the with statement so that you are not re-instantiating the cursor on every iteration.

```
with smtplib.SMTP_SSL(SMTPserver, SMTPport, context=context) as server:
        #time.sleep(1)
        for item in rows:
            server.login(SMTPemail, SMTPpassword)
```